# Files (but not directories) lost from tmpfs

Tags: files, arch-linux, tmp, tmpfs

For the past few weeks (my system hasn't been rebooted in the meanwhile!) I had a bunch of files temporarily placed in `/tmp`

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

I now decided to move them to persistent locations, but I just noticed that those files have disappeared.

The directories I had (and cared about) in `/tmp` are still there though:

```
$ls -ahR /tmp/fysb/
/tmp/fysb/:
./  ../  cm/  desk/  ec/  fds/  rt/  st/

/tmp/fysb/cm:
./  ../

/tmp/fysb/desk:
./  ../

/tmp/fysb/ec:
./  ../

/tmp/fysb/fds:
./  ../  minnie7z/  tv/

/tmp/fysb/fds/minnie7z:
./  ../

/tmp/fysb/fds/tv:
./  ../

/tmp/fysb/rt:
./  ../

/tmp/fysb/st:
./  ../
```

In those directories, I'm 1000% positive, there were dozens of files.

---

What could have happened? Why did those files disappeared? I guess there's no way to recover them? Does tmpfs automatically removes files when the memory is scarce?

For the record, this system (my desktop) has been running for 13 weeks, 5 days, 11 hours, 51 minutes according to `uptime -p`. The running kernel is 4.10.5 (while the installed one is 4.11.7). Due to mismatching between the running and installed software, I've gradually lost functionalities over time (mostly for kernel modules and KDE, my DE). This system has 16 GB of ram, and I suspend it almost every night.

I'm running arch Linux on an x86-64.

Comment: Check for https://serverfault.com/a/377349

Comment: Adding your Linux distribution would narrow it down

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I'm running Arch Linux. As far as I know `/tmp` is never cleared except when the system is shut down. I find it particularly strange how the directories are still there, but the files vanished.

Comment: @peoro Are you saying that in this case (unusually), Arch has replaced the upstream default? https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf